# Number to cents with Nested resources Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have defined  the method:

```
def convert_money_to_cents
  self.price_in_cents = (self.price.to_d * 100).to_i
end
```

in my program.rb Programs have the nested routes Memberships in my routes.rb:

```
resources :programs, except: [:show] do
  resources :memberships, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

I am getting the error:

> undefined method `convert_money_to_cents' for 140:Fixnum
>   when I try to call my method on my instance variable price in my views.

In app/views/memberships/_form.html.erb

```
     <form action="/charge" method="POST">
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_NF4qazGnoW4Z8FLm2HMhDCrQ"
data-image="/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
data-name="Game Store"
data-description="<%= @program.name %>"
data-amount="<%= @program.price.convert_money_to_cents %>">
</script>
</form>
```

How do I need to change my method to work with nested resources?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your are calling `.convert_money_to_cents` method on `@program.price` (in other words, your are calling it on the attribute value, that doesn't have this instance method) while you should call it on `@program` (model instance that has this method).

Comment: Im not sure I understand. I have defined in my memebership controller:   @program=Program.find(params[:program_id]) so calling .convert_money_to_cents doesn't make any sense here

Comment: @Zippo9: is price in the model `Program`?

Comment: yes the table Price has a column of price in it @notulysses

Comment: @Zippo9: how they are related then with `Program` (association)?

Comment: @Zippo9: how `price` table is related to them?

Comment: Price isn't a table it's a column in the program table

Comment: @Zippo9: then goes a question: have you tried my solution?

Comment: @Zippo9, where have you defined the method `convert_money_to_cents`?

Comment: @Zippo9: it should be defined in your `Program` model

Comment: It is defined in my Program model

Comment: And I have restarted the server

Comment: Yes same error still remains  undefined method `convert_money_to_cents' for 140:Fixnum